# Making JSON output "pretty" with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, pretty-print

Hey all I am trying to get my output to look nice on the page using this code I found [Original JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/unLSJ/):

```
 if (!library)
      var library = {};

 library.json = {
      replacer: function(match, pIndent, pKey, pVal, pEnd) {
          var key = '<span class=json-key>';
          var val = '<span class=json-value>';
          var str = '<span class=json-string>';
          var r = pIndent || '';
          if (pKey)
              r = r + key + pKey.replace(/[": ]/g, '') + '</span>: ';
          if (pVal)
              r = r + (pVal[0] == '"' ? str : val) + pVal + '</span>';
          return r + (pEnd || '');
      },
      prettyPrint: function(obj) {
          var jsonLine = /^( *)("[\w]+": )?("[^"]*"|[\w.+-]*)?([,[{])?$/mg;
          return JSON.stringify(obj, null, 3)
              .replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/\\"/g, '&quot;')
              .replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
              .replace(jsonLine, library.json.replacer);
      }
  };
```

However, the output JSON looks like this:
[image]

How can I modify the JS code in order to know that each **"** needs its own line and color? (as it does for the first value, howManyLevels: "5")

Comment: Can you add a JSFiddle with your code that is generating the screenshot? Looks like you need just a bit of CSS (possibly markup like a `<pre>` tag)

Comment: Prism.js is a useful api. [Link](http://prismjs.com)